# How can I get the JqueryUI datepicker show "Today" in the input box

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

When the user selects today in the datepicker, I want the associated input box to show the word "Today".

Is there any reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: No, you really don't want it to show Today, because Today is not a date...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a `.change()` handler to the input that checks the selected date when the value is changed, and updates the value with "Today" if necessary.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/gn4Fj/

```
$('input').datepicker()
    .change(function() {
        var today = new Date().getDate();
        var val = new Date(this.value).getDate();
        if(today === val)
            this.value = "Today";
});
```

Comment: Sounds like I can't really do what I want without some extra work. What I'd really like is for the text box to read things like, "Today", "Yesterday", "Last Wednesday", "Next Tuesday", etc....

Your solution seems like a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking the `showButtonPanel: true` option?